# Does newer version need to contain all features of older version in semantic versioning?

Tags: semantic-versioning

In my project we are trying to switch the release numbering scheme to semantic versioning. We are working on RTL development. The last release of the RTL was 0.83.2.
Then we are working for the new version of RTL and we're making a release targeting to one team A: 1.0.0 (based on 0.83.2 + some features). But in the same time we have to make another release based 0.83.2 for team B which contains other fixes/features and doesn't contain the features from 1.0.0.

My question is how should I name this release: 0.84 ? Is it an issue if 1.0.0 doesn't contain features/fixes from 0.84.

At some point in time features/fixes from 0.84 should be merged into 1.X.X.

Comment: No, newer versions do not need to contain all features of older versions in semantic versioning. Each version should include the changes since the prior version and these changes can be new features, bug fixes, etc. The version number should reflect the amount of change since the prior version. In your example, it would be appropriate to use 0.84 for the release targeting team B since it contains other fixes/features that are not included in 1.0.0. At some point in the future, you may want to merge the features/fixes from 0.84 into a 1.X.X version, but this is not required.

Comment: Ok that means in my 1.0.0 changelog I need to specify the previous version it relates to (0.83.2) otherwise that can be confusing then. So for each release, there should be a pointer to the parent release ?

Comment: Yes, when creating a new version it is important to include a changelog that specifies the changes since the prior version. This is a good practice that helps to ensure that users are aware of what has changed between versions.

Comment: Yes changelog is clear, but here the conclusion is for each new release there must be a pointer to which old release is the parent. For example in our case 1.0.0 -> 0.83.2 and 0.84 -> 0.83.2, That is needed otherwise we could think that 1.0.0 -> 0.84

Comment: Yes, this is a good practice and that helps to ensure that users are aware of what has changed between versions.